# How do I assess the level of liability I will be resposible for when I buy shares of companies listed in the various stock exchanges?

Tags: stock-exchanges, shares

As described in the title, how do I make sure there are no liability when I buy a share of a company listed in the NYC or London stock exchange? What is the process and the terms to look for that can help me assess the liability involved?

Comment: Liability for what? Are you concerned about losing your investment, or about getting sued?

Comment: You basically asked the same question yesterday.

Comment: It is not the same. Yesterday's was about the possibility to be found responsible for debts if the company the shares of which you hold goes bust. Given someone thinks it is possible to be liable, with certain types of stocks, I have asked this one to discover HOW to find out if the stocks you are buying involve such responsibility or not. Make sense?

Comment: The idea of a stock holder being liable for *anything* is absurd.You are never liable in any way; you can always just throw your stocks in the trash.

Comment: I am afraid it's not absurd, just very hard to see it happening. Here's an interesting link: http://nationalparalegal.edu/public_documents/courseware_asp_files/businessLaw/RightsOfShareholders/LiabilityOfShareholders.asp. In particular the paragraph on open corporations.